# Java - How to make my code use less memory?

Tags: java, hadoop, memory, jvm, hdfs

I have a data generator that writes data to HDFS text file. It throws

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

error when dataset is very big. How to make it use less mem?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (Record record : dataSet) {
    sb.append(record.getCsvData());
    sb.append("\n");
}

byte[] byt = sb.toString().getBytes();
FSDataOutputStream fsOutStream = fs.create(newFilePath);
fsOutStream.write(byt);
fsOutStream.close();
```

Comment: Instead of building one enormous string, why not write each line to the file as you pull it out of the data set?

Comment: That's a valuable advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing a big `StringBuilder` to store everything, write one record at a time to the file.

Untested example:

```
try(FSDataOutputStream fsOutStream = fs.create(newFilePath)) {
    for (Record record : dataSet) {
        fsOutStream.write(record.getCsvData().getBytes());
    }
}
```